# Tracking sharing of a link on facebook and timestamp of a Like

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-sharer, restfb

I am developing a website,there are some "facebook like" buttons.If some one likes one of the link from my website HomePage it is posted in the wall of the respective person, and i get the post_id. I want to track all the activity done on the posted Link (i.e. like,comments,share).

1. I am able to track the comments and likes upto the first level (i.e if some one shares the link, then I am not able to track the related likes / comments of the shared link).
2. If more than one person is liking the same link from my homepage I am tracking by the post_id individually, is there any way that I can track by the link itself so that regardless whoever liked from my website I will get the like & comment details.
3. Is it possible to get the timestamp of a like (When a person likes the shared link).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can request the 'manage_notifications' permission which will allow you to read their notifications. the user would need to have notifications enabled for when someone likes or shares their post (by default this is the case). The notification object includes the other friend's id.  more here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification/

2 and 3:  You could use javascript and get the user's fb ID as well as the time on the page itself and do stuff with it (this should work):

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
      function(response) {
        msg = "user id " + response.authResponse.userID + "liked this page at" + Date();
        console.log(msg);
       }
    );
```

More info https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Comment: Will it return the user id who is liking the shared url from the facebook wall.

Comment: you should be able to get that via the notifications object of the user using the key sender_id